# iOS app crashes on iOS 12 beta 9 and earlier only when downloaded from Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight, beta, xcode10, ios12

The app works in Debug and Release mode when launched from XCode 10 beta 6 and earlier onto iOS 12 beta 9 and earlier.

The app crashes on startup (only when downloaded from Testflight) after showing the launch screen for a second or two.

The app works on iOS 11 and iOS 10 when installed via Testflight as well as XCode.

I thought newer releases of the betas may fix the problem but the problem has persisted through each XCode 10 beta, iOS 12 beta, and macOS Mojave beta update.

I added logs that write to a file locally on the device, these logs show that I am not getting past the initial webview.

There are no crash logs from testflight in Organizer for the build.

Comment: Published Testflight builds should offer crash reports in Xcode>Organizer.

Comment: there are no crash reports for this build in XCode.

Comment: I would suggest adding some crash reporting and see what turns up.

Comment: Experiencing the same. Using the released iOS12. Found a solution?

Comment: Getting the same thing here too. I checked the device console, and I am getting this error:

Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID